# In R ,how can I split one column to two columns? Thanks

Tags: r, dataframe

there is a data.frame as blow

```
myindex
234yua
1w
678tw@s
```

how can i add new columns "mynumber""mychart". the wished dataframe as blow.

```
myindex mynumber mychart
234yua   234      yua
1w       1        w
678tw@s   678     tw@s
```

anyone can help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `dplyr::mutate` call:

```r
 dplyr::mutate(df, mynumber = gsub("^(\\d+).*$", "\\1", myindex),
                   mychart = gsub("^(\\d+)(.*)$", "\\2", myindex))
#>   myindex mynumber mychart
#> 1  234yua      234     yua
#> 2      1w        1       w
#> 3 678tw@s      678    tw@s
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% extract(col = myindex, into = c('mynumber','mychart'), regex = '(\\d+)([a-z]+[[:punct:]]?[a-z]?)', remove = F)
  myindex mynumber mychart
1  234yua      234     yua
2      1w        1       w
3 678tw@s      678    tw@s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this `base R` solution:

```
#Code
mydf$mychart <- gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", mydf$myindex)
mydf$mynumber <- gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", mydf$myindex)
```

Output:

```
  myindex mychart mynumber
1  234yua     yua      234
2      1w       w        1
3 678tw@s    tw@s      678
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
mydf <- structure(list(myindex = c("234yua", "1w", "678tw@s")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `strsplit` here, for a base R option:

```r
s_list <- strsplit(df$myindex, "(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])", perl=TRUE)
df$mynumber <- lapply(s_list, function(x) x[1])
df$mychart <- lapply(s_list, function(x) x[2])
df

  myindex mynumber mychart
1  234yua      234     yua
2      1w        1       w
3 678tw@s      678    tw@s
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(myindex = c("234yua", "1w", "678tw@s"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The strategy/appeal of this approach is to split the column value at the boundary between numbers on the left, and lowercase letters on the right.  This works well for the exact data you showed, but would probably be workable even if you have other edge cases not shown.

Answer (score 1):

This `stringr` solution works too (assuming that the numeric and the non-numeric parts are contiguous):

```
library(stringr)
df$mynumber <- str_extract(df$myindex, "\\d+")
df$mychart <- str_extract(df$myindex, "[^\\d]+")
```

Result:

```
df
  myindex mynumber mychart
1  234yua      234     yua
2      1w        1       w
3 678tw@s      678    tw@s
```